# Dojo Tree, how to switch/change icon style

Tags: javascript, tree, dojo

i have a dijit/Tree and override the getIconClass function to change the icon symbols. This works fine, but how can i change the item by onClick on the leaf?
By loading the tree all icons are set right. My Leafs has a attribute that can be true/false, called "doTest". In the getIconClass function i set the icon style to "foo" when "doTest" is true and to "bar" when "doTest" is false. By onClick of the leaf the "doTest" attribute switchs to true/false but the icon is still the same. Is there a way to change the icon by clicking on my leaf?

```
var myTree = new Tree({
            // Setze wurzel
            data : myModel,
            getIconClass : function(item) {
                if (item.type == "Root") {
                    return "allServer";
                }
                if (item.type == "Server") {
                    return (item.available ? "serverAktive"
                            : "serverInAktive");
                }
                if (item.type == "Service") {

                    return (item.doTest ? "doPerformanceTest"
                            : "doNoPerformanceTest");
                }


            },
            onClick : function(item) {
                // Function set the Value of doTest to false or true.
                 setDoTest(item);
                // Here must be a way to Change the icon!!!!

            },
            onDblClick : function(item) {
                if (item.type == "Server") {
                    // doPerformanceTest für alle true/false
                    var services = myObsStore.getChildren(item);
                    var setTo = true;
                    services.forEach(function(element, index) {
                        if (index == 0) {
                            if (element.doTest) {
                                setTo = false;
                            }
                        }
                        // Change the Icon of all!!!!
                    });
                }
            },
            model : myModel
        }).placeAt("navigationView");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we would like to see the "setDoTest" function, especially the part where you set the item's value. 
I'd set the value like this

```
myTree.model.store.setValue(item, "doTest", testState);
```

Update:

In our project, we are using the older api with ItemFileWriteStore hence the missing setValue.

Also, this reading might be useful to you : [(dojo) Observable cannot observe changes in Memory Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178792/dojo-observable-cannot-observe-changes-in-memory-store). You will read there that the changes need to be done via Observable object not the store itself (Memory).

From what I can get from the documentation, you should probably use the

```
observable.put(updatedItem)
```

method in order to do the update on the item so the observable can notify the model. Please note, that ".put" method has a second parameter carrying optional parameters.

I've setup [js fiddle sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/rvuBU/). The sample demonstrates the way to update property of the clicked item so the model is propeprly notified, so the iconClass is properly applied. The sample turns the continent's class to "unknownContinent" after clicking it.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Oh okay,

here is the doTest function:

```
function setDoTest(item) {
            if (item.type == "Service") {
                if (item.doTest == true) {
                    item.doTest = false;
                } else {
                    item.doTest = true;
                }
                alert("service doTest:" + item.doTest);

                // change the Icon???
            }
        }
```

And here my store

```
// Store für den Tree
        var myStore = new Memory({
            // Setze die Wurzel
            data : [ serverRoot ],
            getChildren : function(object) {
                return this.query({
                    parent : object.id
                });
            }
        });

        // Wrapp den store in Observable für updates
        var myObsStore = new Observable(myStore);

        // Initialisiere Model und setze Store
        var myModel = new ObjectStoreModel({
            store : myObsStore,
            // Wurzel setzen
            query : {
                id : "root"
            }
        });
```

Comment: please see my updated answer above with jsfiddle demo